# Issue with removing displayed list of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I am creating a restaurant menu app that a waiter can use to input orders.**

I have everything set to where when I `select` an **food item button**. That item is **added to a list of chosen items** for purchase in a list displayed on screen.

I have **remove buttons** next to **each item** in case you want to remove one. The remove button works, however it **always removes the first item from the list** and not the item that had it's particular remove button selected.

**I'm not sure why it is doing this. What could I do to get the current item removed that had it's particular remove button selected?**

**Js code**

```
 .controller('orderAddCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'dataService', function ($scope, $location, dataService) {

            $scope.chosenItems = [];
            $scope.totalItemPrices = 0;

            $scope.userId = "";

            $scope.addOrderToList = function (item) {
                $scope.addPricesToTotalItemPrices(item.itemPrice);
                $scope.chosenItems.push({'Name': item.itemName, 'Price': item.itemPrice});
            };

            $scope.addPricesToTotalItemPrices = function (price) {
                $scope.totalItemPrices += price ;
            };

            $scope.removePricesFromTotalItemPrices = function (price) {
                $scope.totalItemPrices -= price;
            };


            $scope.removeFromOrderToList = function (item) {
                $scope.removePricesFromTotalItemPrices(item.Price);
                $scope.chosenItems.splice(item, 1);
            };
```

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Food Items</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-success col-3" ng-repeat="item in Items" ng-click="addOrderToList(item)">{{item.itemName}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Item Price</th>
                        <th>Total Price: ${{totalItemPrices}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="i in chosenItems">
                        <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Price}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeFromOrderToList(i)">
                                Remove
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: By the way, `splice()` isn't being used correctly in `$scope.removeFromOrderToList`. It should take a numeric index as a first argument, not an object reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the splice syntax:

> array.splice(startindex, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)
>   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

If you pass a string as a parameter where an integer is expected it will, in the case of splice, first attempt to parse the string as an integer.

When the parse returns NaN it will default to 0, which explains the behavior of your code.